# Scrolling visual studio phone emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I need help with scrollviewer in emulator. In xaml everything about it is ok, but in emulator i have... hmm bug? or it's my bad. When I want to scroll down, it goes down ... 1/3 of all screen... and when I release it automatically goes up to previous position (starting position)
I don't know if it is my bad,or emulator bug...

```xml
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="Excercises.Weider_s_six"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d" shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF1FB0DB">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>



        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->

        <ScrollViewer>
            <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0" Height="1500">

                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,15,0,85" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Name="TextBlock1" TextWrapping="Wrap"> 
                <LineBreak />
            <Run FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontSize="27" FontWeight="ExtraBlack" TextDecorations="Underline">
               Weider 6 pack Training is a perfect exercise for flat stomach. 
                </Run>
                <LineBreak />
            <Run Text="This easy training programme has many advantages." FontSize="27" />
            <LineBreak />
            <Run Text="1. It's perfect for beginners and for experts" FontWeight="ExtraBlack" TextDecorations="Underline" FontSize="27" />
            <Run Text=" – exercises are easy and begin with the basic level, so every beginner can use them but they get more complicated pretty fast so advanced sportsmen can also be interested in them." FontSize="27" />
            <LineBreak />
            <Run Text="2.It helps not only carve your muscles but also burn fat" FontWeight="ExtraBlack" TextDecorations="Underline" FontSize="27" />
            <Run Text=" – during the exercise you not only use your abdominal rectus but you also move your legs and arms. It is also because W6 puts pressure on the number of repetitions. It carves your muscles but also burns fat. You can train W6 for about 40 minutes without taking any breaks – you use up all glycogen in blood and start burning the fat." FontSize="27" />
            <LineBreak />
            <Run Text="3.It is easy " FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="ExtraBlack" TextDecorations="Underline" FontSize="27" />
            <Run Text="– it is a really easy training set which you can train almost anywhere. All you need is flat ground." FontSize="27" />
            <LineBreak />
            <Run Text="4.It gives excellent results" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="ExtraBlack" TextDecorations="Underline" FontSize="27" />
            <Run Text=" – if you want to have a flat stomach W6 is designed just for you. You can see the first effects after just a week and after a whole series it is really impressive." FontSize="27" />"
            <LineBreak />
                </TextBlock>



            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>

    </Grid>


    <!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
    <!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: Remove the Height from your Grid. and either delete the RowDefinitions to your outer grid, or add another item. The ScrollViewer should be in the Grid.Row where the value is *

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused because the ScrollViewer doesn't know how much space it can take up before it needs to scroll and so takes up infinite space and therefore doens't need to scroll it's content. The bounce you are seeing is what happens when you try to move beyond the end of the scrollviewers container.

You could probably solve this by removing the RowDefinitions from LayoutRoot as it's the only item in the grid.

Currently it's in a row which can grow as large as it needs to (that's what setting the row height to "Auto" means). This is regardless of the grid space. You need to limit the amout of space the ScrollViewer can occupy so it knows it needs to scroll it's content.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things you need to change here to get it to work correctly.  First of all, your ScrollViewer really should be within the grid.  Second of all, get rid of the Height on your grid.  It winds up looking like this:

```xml
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF1FB0DB">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>



    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->

  <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0" >
    <ScrollViewer>

      <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,15,0,85" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Name="TextBlock1"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap">
        <LineBreak />
        <Run FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontSize="27" FontWeight="ExtraBlack" TextDecorations="Underline">
          Weider 6 pack Training is a perfect exercise for flat stomach.
        </Run>
        <LineBreak />
        <Run Text="This easy training programme has many advantages." FontSize="27" />
        <LineBreak />
        <Run Text="1. It's perfect for beginners and for experts" FontWeight="ExtraBlack"
             TextDecorations="Underline" FontSize="27" />
        <Run
            Text=" – exercises are easy and begin with the basic level, so every beginner can use them but they get more complicated pretty fast so advanced sportsmen can also be interested in them." FontSize="27" />
        <LineBreak />
        <Run Text="2.It helps not only carve your muscles but also burn fat" FontWeight="ExtraBlack"
             TextDecorations="Underline" FontSize="27" />
        <Run Text=" – during the exercise you not only use your abdominal rectus but you also move your legs and arms. It is also because W6 puts pressure on the number of repetitions. It carves your muscles but also burns fat. You can train W6 for about 40 minutes without taking any breaks – you use up all glycogen in blood and start burning the fat." FontSize="27" />
        <LineBreak />
        <Run Text="3.It is easy " FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="ExtraBlack" TextDecorations="Underline"
             FontSize="27" />
        <Run Text="– it is a really easy training set which you can train almost anywhere. All you need is flat ground." FontSize="27" />
        <LineBreak />
        <Run Text="4.It gives excellent results" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="ExtraBlack"
             TextDecorations="Underline" FontSize="27" />
        <Run Text=" – if you want to have a flat stomach W6 is designed just for you. You can see the first effects after just a week and after a whole series it is really impressive." FontSize="27" />
        "
        <LineBreak />
      </TextBlock>


    </ScrollViewer>
  </Grid>

</Grid>
```